# Прием файла через сокет на стороне клиента. С++

Tags: visual-c++

Здравсвуйте!
Теперь остался последний этап в моей задаче. Сервер отсылает нормально блоки искомого файла клиенту. Осталось склеить их на стороне клиента.
Вопрос пока чисто теоретический:  как клиент поймет какой ему файл создавать ( с каким расширением), чтобы туда записывать принимаемые от сервера блоки?

```
 Сервер
 //Отправка файла
 int i = 0;
 int b;
 int a = atoi(buffer);
 char * buff = new char[a];
 d:
 while(!feof(in)) 
 {
 b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in);
 send(client_socket,&buff[0],b,0);
 i++;
 printf("Send %d block file \n", i);
 recv(client_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE ,0); 
 if (!strcmp(&buffer[0], "Принимаю поблочно файл!"))
 goto d;
 }
 fclose(in);
 printf("File successfully send clienty\n");
 system("PAUSE");

 Клиент
 //Прием файла
  else
  {
      f:
      int nbytes = recv( my_socket, &buff[0], sizeof(buff), 0 );   
      if ( nbytes == 0)  
      {     
          printf("\nПередача файла завершена\n"); 
          system("pause");
          fclose(RecFile);
          return -1;   
      }   
      if (nbytes < 0)   
      {    
          printf("Ошибка в передаче файла \n"); 
          return -1;   
      } 
      RecFile = fopen ("C:/receve.txt","at"); 
      fwrite(buff, 1, strlen(buff), RecFile);
      fclose(RecFile);
      strcpy(&buff1[0], "Принимаю поблочно файл!");
      int n1 = strlen(buff1);  
      send(my_socket, buff1, (n1-1), 0);
      goto f;
  }
  system("pause");
  }
```

Comment: сами пишем имя искомого файла

Comment: Страсти какие. А нельзя ли текст клиента и сервера добавить в вопрос (только, пожалуйста, нового вопроса создавать не надо).

Comment: @АннаХатико, после отправки всех блоков файла закройте в сервере сокет. В клиенте пишите в fwrite() ровно столько байт, сколько вернул recv(). Когда recv() вернет 0, данные закончились, просто закрывайте сокет и файл в клиенте.

Comment: спасибо, эти проблемы решились. только передача у меня сейчас для .txt  работает только, что делать с другими расширениями?

Comment: как сделать чтобы можно было передать файл любого расширения?

Comment: А чем, собственно, txt-файл принципиально отличается от любого другого файла? Лишь суффиксом. Через сокет ведь всё равно, какие данные передавать, бинарные или текстовые.

Answer (score 3):

[@АннаХатико](/users/9320/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE), извините, но это (по меньшей мере) странный код. Зачем Вы в цикле отправки блоков файла что-то принимаете от клиента, а он (соответственно) передает. Это **абсолютно** лишнее.

Видимо правильным был бы следующий очень простой протокол обмена:

```
Cli:       connect
Cli->Serv: размер-блока имя-файла-завершающееся-нулем
Serv->Cli: послать все байты файла, каждый send() посылает блок
           последний send() может послать меньше, чем блок
Serv:      close file, close socket
Cli:       close socket, close file
```

Разницы для типов (расширений файлов) никакой нет

Answer (score 2):

```
Сервер
 //Отправка файла
 int i = 0;
 int b;
 int a = atoi(buffer);
 char * buff = new char[a];
 d:                           // зачем тут метка. Тут уже есть цикл while,
                              // который благодаря d: -- goto d; вырождается в if
 while(!feof(in)) 
 {
 b = fread(&buff[0],1,a,in);
 send(client_socket,&buff[0],b,0);
 i++;
 printf("Send %d block file \n", i);
 recv(client_socket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE ,0);          // это требование преподавателя? Или самостоятельное творчество?
 if (!strcmp(&buffer[0], "Принимаю поблочно файл!"))  // Лишняя деталь. Если strcmp даёт 0, то возвращаетесь к началу цикла по goto, иначе -- переход по реализации while.
 goto d;            // 
 }
 fclose(in);
 printf("File successfully send clienty\n");
 system("PAUSE");

 Клиент
 //Прием файла
  else
  {
      f:                    // вполне заменяется циклом while ((nbytes = ...) > 0)
      int nbytes = recv( my_socket, &buff[0], sizeof(buff), 0 );   
      if ( nbytes == 0)  
      {     
          printf("\nПередача файла завершена\n"); 
          system("pause");
          fclose(RecFile);     // А он уже закрыт.
          return -1;   
      }   
      if (nbytes < 0)   
      {    
          printf("Ошибка в передаче файла \n"); 
          return -1;   
      } 
      RecFile = fopen ("C:/receve.txt","at"); // зачем его постоянно открывать/закрывать (да ещё перед каждым запуском удалять ручками)?
      fwrite(buff, 1, strlen(buff), RecFile); // Вместо strlen(buff) лучше бы nbytes
      fclose(RecFile);
      strcpy(&buff1[0], "Принимаю поблочно файл!"); // квитанция. Нафига, tcp это сам делает
      int n1 = strlen(buff1);  
      send(my_socket, buff1, (n1-1), 0); // Отбрасываем ненужный восклицательный знак
                                         // Правильно, надо быть скромнее.
      goto f;
  }
  system("pause");
  }
```

Ну вот где-то так.

Comment: все-таки непонятно


    RecFile = fopen ("C:/receve.txt","at"); 
    // зачем его постоянно   открывать/закрывать (да ещё перед каждым 
    запуском удалять ручками)? 


 А куда же тогда писать эти блоки? И для любых расширений тем более..

Comment: Так Вы его откройте перед началом приёма (причём можно и не на добавление ("a"), а на запись ("w") и после окончания приёма (nbytes == 0) закройте. Да, а что за проблема с расширениями? (пока только вижу бяку strlen(buff) для данных, содержащий нулевые байты).

Comment: @АннаХатико, насколько я могу понять у Вас реально проблема в том, что клиент и сервер работают на одном компьютере, поэтому клиент не может писать в файл с тем же именем, что он запрашивал у сервера. Так?

--

Если так, то пусть клиент просто пишет принимаемые файлы на другой диск (например на флешку). Поменяйте в клиенте имя диска при открытии файла, скажем, с C: на F: (или какая у Вас флешка?)

Для тестов сойдет.

Answer (score 1):

Как услышал про txt. Зачем открываешь файлы как текстовые? Открывай как бинарные. "ab" в fopen ("C:/receve.txt","ab"); И содержимое файла тебя больше не должно волновать.

Хм, а это не клиент запрашивает у сервера файл? Тогда он должен знать под каким именем сохранить.

Да, прием файла сделан не очень хорошо. Обычно программы подобного типа подключаются к серверу, создают у себя нужный файл и скачивают содержимое.

Я смотрю на код и в голове крутятся протоколы TFTP, FTP и HTTP в конце концов. Они интересны тем, что максимально простые и широко используемые и из них можно многому научиться.

Comment: Объясните, чем эти протоколы проще создаваемой Анной лабораторной работы. Особенно TFTP, который вообще должен учитывать нарушение порядка прихода пакетов и их возможную потерю.

И, кстати, напомните, описание http сколько страниц занимает?


"Я знаю карате, дзюдо, самбо, джиуджитсу и ещё много страшных слов" (c) Фоменко.

Comment: Не в обиду будет сказано, но их реализация воспринимается проще, чем предоставленный исходный код. Даже реализация TFTP. Там кстати клиент(циска) просто запрашивал части файла по порядку, сервер отдавал что попросили. Офигенный и простой протокол, оставил впечатление.

Я не читал описание http, не знаю какой там объем. Сам по себе протокол очень простой. Я уже несколько серверов написал.

Comment: Это проще, чем лабораторка @АннаХотико? С tftp'шными ретрансмитами? Месье понимает толк в извращениях. К тому же подозреваю, что по условиям задачи необходимо использовать tcp, а там эти хитрости уже внутри протокола.

Comment: Ага. Если переписать лабораторную @АннаХотико, она станет проще, но сейчас сложнее. TFTP сервер вообще не волнуется и выдает запрашиваемые данные. Клиент знает размер части файла, запросил 10 частей, получил, сохранил. Если не получил посылает запросы еще раз.
(Чувствую мы сейчас договоримся до того, что я напишу TFTP и погоняю пакеты через WiFi.)

Comment: @mikelsv Бог в помощь. Протокол действительно простой (хотя и за счёт скорости -- на каждый пакет -- квиток) , а WiFi, как я понимаю, работает надёжно, так что сделать это недолго.

Comment: @mikelsv, сейчас протокол у Анны проще некуда. Даже об ошибках не сообщает (о таймаутах я вообще не говорю). Просто программа пока не написана.